# How to download web view contents like PDF or images?

Tags: android, webview, android-download-manager

```
     Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Savenotes);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_ONLY_COMPLETION);

            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
        }
```

I am trying to download the contents which is present in webview.I am using download manager but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
  {
   public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
   {
    //for downloading directly through download manager
    Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    dm.enqueue(request);
   }
  });
```

Comment: For PDF I am using  final String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;       and on button press nothing is happening

Comment: do you want to download file inside webview or on button click ? or question said you want to download from webview

Comment: on btn click I want to download the file in memory

Comment: In webview I am showing a pdf  and on button click i want to save  that pdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}});
```